# ¿Cómo Modificar el Dropdown de los Atributos de un Custom Post Type en Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, filtro

Estoy intentando modificar la lista de las páginas que se muestra en el metabox de los atributos de página de un 'custom post type', pero no lo he encontrado.

He colocado lo siguiente en functions.php:

```
function filter_dropdown_so_14880043( $dropdown_args, $post ){

$my_args = array(
    'post_type'        => $post->post_type,
    'exclude_tree'     => $post->ID,
    'selected'         => $post->post_parent,
    'name'             => 'parent_id',
    'show_option_none' => 'Categoría de Curso',
    'echo'             => 0,
    'sort_order'       => 'DESC',
    'sort_column'      => 'post_date',
    'parent'           => 0
);
return $my_args;
}
add_filter( 'page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args', 'filter_dropdown_so_14880043', 10, 2 );
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no he tenido éxito... puedo cambiar el "empty value", pero la lista no.

¿Qué hago mal?

Comment: Jorge, veo que nadie responde :( ... de verdad nunca he visto lo que quiero hacer, pero a ver, "todo" es posible no? xD

Answer (score 0):

Explico un poco mejor

Tengo varias Paginas en un CPT en concreto, pero siempre estarán 2 paginas repetidas (nombre), ya que uno tendrá asignado una categoría (Presencial) y otro (Virtual)... cuando se añade una pagina nueva, se le asignaría manualmente una de las 2 categorías y manualmente el padre debe de ser alguno de las 2 paginas con el mismo titulo...

En el Dropdown, solo sale el nombre de pagina por lo que es imposible determinar cual es la categoría de cada una de las paginas.

Pense ¿podríamos concatenar al page_title el term_name?

Ejemplo:

Si esta asi:

```
<li>[nombre de la pagina]</li>
```

Pues, filtrar con los hooks para añadirle algo asi..

```
<li>[nombre de la pagina] - [nombre de la categoria]</li>
```

Espero que me haya aclarado mejor

Comment: nadie? ... como que es complicado por lo que veo.... :(